Creating subpages for each custom post type
I have a custom post type (created with ACF), called shops.
Each shop has data for example about working hours, which are separated in each custom field (Monday, Tuesday, wednesday etc.).
I have all the info on single page of each shop, for example on mysite.com/shop/shop-name/, and my question is, how can I create a subpage for each shop which will have an url like this: mysite.com/shop/shop-name/working-hours/ on which I will put the data about working hours?
I've looked at hierarchical Custom Post Types but didn't understand if that is what I am looking for.
Thank you

Yes, setting the hierarchical option to true when you register the custom post type will mean each of your "shop pages" can have child "shop pages." So you could have
example.com/shop/shop-name/
example.com/shop/shop-name/hours/
example.com/shop/shop-name/contact/

etc.
I believe ACF has a simple toggle to enable the hierarchical option. If you were registering it in code, you would just set that to true.

Yes, there is an option hierarchical in ACF. However does that mean that for each shop-name I need to create subpages (hours), or I only need to create it once (hours) and it will be applied for each shop-name (since working hours data is already in shop-name)?

If you want to automate the sub-pages, then I would recommend using add_rewrite_rule() to create virtual pages.

If you just use the hierarchical option, you would need to add subpages everywhere you want them. It doesn't create a corresponding subpage like "hours" for every parent page automatically.
